# Adobe CQ5 copy entire website to another server

Tags: export, adobe, aem

I used Package Manager to download the content from Adobe CQ5 and imported it to the test server. Also downloaded and uploaded Digital Assets.

The question is how do I get the webpages? After the content was imported I don't see in WCM any pages of the project.

Comment: Can you describe steps how you are doing this process? Also share some screenshots.

Comment: How does your filter look when you package content in one server ? And what does the log say when you install the package in the test server ?

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying me.  As I haven't got reply here, I posted the same question in the Adobe forum. There I got the reply very quickly. The reason was that I didn't generate a package with filter that points to the content.